# Using PEAR to deploy a PHP web app?

Tags: deployment, pear

Is it possible to package a PHP web app into PEAR format for automatic deployment? Like this:

```
pear install myPackage
```

and, to upgrade:

```
pear upgrade myPackage
```

But because I have a web app, I also need this to activate my web app on Apache config files.

From what I'm aware of, PEAR mostly contains libraries - but I've heard that it can be used to deploy complete web applications too. There's no information I could find regarding the subject. So I want to know is it possible that PEAR can also interact with web servers like Apache to manage creation of virtual hosts depending on my application?

Anyone already doing this?

Will appreciate your answers. Thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for something like you and this link [**here**](http://www.eschrade.com/page/deployment-pear-4c228790/) was the best resource I found. It explains pretty precisely what would one need to do to get his package set up as a PEAR repository, which could be easily installed at client machine in standard PEAR install ways.

Answer (score 1):

The PEAR installer is not directly able to modify your Apache vhost files, but you can write your own plugin that does that and gets automatically called when installing/upgrading.

Files in a PEAR package have a ["role"](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.developers.package2.file.php#guide.developers.package2.file.roles), for example `php`, `test`, `doc` and `www`. `www` is the one you want to use for public HTML, javascript and CSS files.

Apart from that, you can use your own roles and do things when files with that role get installed. Alternatively, you can also use post-install scripts in packages to restart your webserver or so.

Examples of a web applications deployed with PEAR are:

- The PEAR website itself, http://pear.php.net/package/pearweb/
- SemanticScuttle, a bookmark manager: http://semanticscuttle.sourceforge.net/pirum.html